# unproportionately sort cost of explain plan

Tags: oracle, performance, sorting, sql-execution-plan

I have a very small table - MTS_METRIC (25 rows).

I'm executing a heavy query, that includes this table (and more tables of course..)

when I'm checking the explain plan, there is a strange thing.

The optimizer makes a sorting on the data of the table (in goal to perform "sort

merge join" in the next step), and the cost of the sort is really huge - 2,860K!

How can it be?

```
    | id  | Operation                                | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    |  31 |           BUFFER SORT                    |                              |     1 |    39 |       |  2860K  (1)| 02:23:03 |
    |  32 |            VIEW                          |                              |     1 |    39 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |  33 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | MTS_METRIC                   |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |* 34 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | MTS_METRIC_IDX1              |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Comment: I don't see the costs in your execution plan.  Off the top of my head, for such a small table having only 25 rows, the optimizer may not be choosing the path you might expect, e.g. by not using an index because it won't help.

Comment: Tim, this is the cost: 2860K. I don't know why you cant see it.
I don't want the optimizer behave like I expect - I just want to understand how he takes tables with 25 rows - filter on it with unique index and make so huge sort. It's not make sense.

Comment: can you post the query that produced this plan? the buffer sort is probably on some massive intermediate set, not your 25 row table.

Comment: A sliver of an explain plan on its own makes no sense. If you can't post the whole you will have to figure out things for yourself.